# JVM Pact Dsl body for a map of collections

Tags: java, json, pact-jvm

I am going to model a map of collection as the response of my provider using pact dsl, But I can not figure out how. I appreciate if somebody can help me on this.

```
Map<String, Collection<myObject>> responseBody;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I could model it:

```
DslPart respBody = new PactDslJsonBody()
            .object("object name")
                .eachKeyMappedToAnArrayLike("key of the map")
                    //myObject body
                .closeArray()
            .closeObject();
```